# Python3, How can the user change the plots he/she wants to see in bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, bokeh

I want to display one histogram at a time and have the user click on the year he/she wants to see without refreshing the page. I have three different histograms of three different years and want to add a radiogroup to change the year. How could I implement that?

I have tried a lot of different things and this is the most recent:

```
radio_group = RadioGroup(
    labels=["2016", "2017", "2018"], active=0)

layout = layout([widgetbox(radio_group)], [plot2016, plot2017, plot2018])

show(layout)
```

The result of the radio_group should go into the layout.

I know I should probably use JavaScript callbacks somewhere but I have no idea how.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some code what you tried already. Thanks!

Comment: @David added a little bit but have deleted most of the things I have already tried, sorry.

Comment: Are you deploying the bokeh plot in a jupyter notebook, statically (single HTML file) or via the bokeh server?

Comment: @syntonym via a single HTML file.